# Hold Values of DensityPlot to use for an other DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, hold

I have two surface functions, `f[x,y]` and `g[x,y]`. Assuming that the `DensityPlot` of `f` and `g` takes a while, is there a way to hold the values of `DensityPlot`, to efficiently `DensityPlot` `f[x,y]-g[x,y]` ?

I'm aware that the mesh used by `DensityPlot` for the two functions `f` and `g` is not necessary the same, depending on variations of these functions. However, maybe it is possible to inform `DensityPlot` to start with the pre-computed values of `DensityPlot[f]` and `DensityPlot[g]` when asking for `DensityPlot[f-g]`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: `ListDensityPlot` can show values calculated on an explicit grid.

Comment: I would rather avoid setting an explicit grid, or at least use the one that `DensityPlot` did propose

Comment: `FunctionInterpolation` might give a more efficiently computed approximation to each function.

Comment: Could you be more explicit ?